# Separating logic from Express router and still access Express functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, model-view-controller

I've started to write my first app with Node.js and Express, but my router file is becoming quite cluttered. In my opinion, it contains too much logic.

I'm trying to pass a function in another file (Parent.controller.js) to the router rather than putting my logic in an anonymous function.

So, like this:

`Router.post('/create-child', Parent.createChild);`

Rather than this:

```
Router.post('/create-child', function(req, res, next) {
    // do something
    // do something else
    // do even more stuff
    // this is getting messy
    // oh dear
});
```

But I don't know how to trigger redirects, or save flash data, from the function in `Parent.controller.js`. This is because I'm not sure how to still access the `req`, `res` objects from `Parent.controller.js`. Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`req` and `res` are just ordinary objects passed as arguments to the controller function. You don't have to require anything special in *Parent.controller.js*. Just make sure the parameters for `createChild` are `req`, `res`. And `next` if  you needed. Like so:

```
module.exports.createChild = (req, res, next) => {
   res.status(200).json({ message: 'OK' });
}
```

You will, of course, have to require express in the routes file:

```
const express = require('express');
const Parent = require('Parent.controller');

const router = express.Router();

Router.post('/create-child', Parent.createChild);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap all functions in an object and export it like so -

Parent.controller.js

```
function createChild(req, res, next) {
  // do your thing here
}

// Add more functions

// Export module

module.exports = {
  createChild,
  ... // other functions
}
```

Then add it in router like so -

```
const Parent = require('./Parent.controller.js');

Router.post('/create-child', Parent.createChild);
```

Or you can go the class route -

Parent.controller.js

```
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    // fill constructor info
  }

  createChild(req, res, next) {
    // do your thing here
  }
}

module.exports = Parent;
```

Your router -

```
const Parent = require('./Parent.controller.js');
const parent = new Parent();

Router.post('/create-child', parent.createChild);
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly have you tried? Accessing `req,res` should be pretty straightforward,

```
(module.exports.)createChild = function(req,res){
    childName = req.child_name; 
    ..........
    your child genesis code
    .....
    res.send('Child created')
}
```

As per redirects, you can trigger them with `res.redirect()`, however, if you want to redirect the user onto an another page, I'd recommend you `res.status(307).send` or something like that to your front-end which will catch the status code and trigger a `window.assign()` or something like that.